# Check if record exists in database using Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am inserting an xml file contents into a DB from my localstorage. However what happens is that the xml file can be updated and when its updated i need to check if the record already exists or not in my DB. If it exists i need to update the record and if it doesn't exist i need to insert a new record. I am able to do the insert but I dont seem to find a Laravel way to do this using update method.

In my xml file they is a node that doesn't change value when the xml has been updated. I am thinking I must use an if statement to check against this node's value but I cant seem to get my head around this.

Below is how I am doing my insert.

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    // Building directory path.
    $directory = storage_path('app/xmlentries/uploads');

    $files = File::allFiles($directory);

    foreach($files as $file) {

    $contents = $file->getContents();

    foreach((array) $contents as $content)
    {
        $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

        $data = [
        'requisition' => $simpleXml->ExportData->Requisition['clientReqId'], //NODE THAT DOES NOT CHANGE VALUE
        'experience' => $simpleXml->ExportData->Requisition->EssentialFunction,
        'job_requirements' => $simpleXml->ExportData->Requisition->EssentialFunction,
        ],
        ];

        Vacancy::insert($data); //WHERE I AM INSERTING MY RECORD

    }

    }
    }
```

How would I update the record if it already exists?

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-inserts

If you use Eloquent you don't need a "if" in your controller
the "save" method will see it for you, if your PKs was correctly configured in your model

The "Vacancy" is your model right? put every attribute in an object

```
$vacancy = new Vencancy();
$vacancy->requisition = $simpleXml->ExportData->Requisition['clientReqId'];
$vacancy->save();
```

try it with all your attributes.... 
see your primary key [link]https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models[/link]

Comment: The "Vacancy" is your model right? put every attribute in an object
`code`$vacancy = new Vencancy();
$vacancy->requisition = $simpleXml->ExportData->Requisition['clientReqId'];
$vacancy->save();
`code`
try it with all your attributes.... 
see your primary key [link]https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models[/link]

Comment: Vacancy is my model.